# How to change color lines to gradient color depending on the value

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, ngx-charts

How to change lines color using **ngx-chart** ? The goal is to have a color that change depending on the `yAxis`, with a gradient color.

It seems that if I change the `schemeType` from `ordinal` to `linear`, it does what I want to, but this remove the legends.

Like this exemple :

[image: gradient line]

[Related GitHub issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HJJN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what I wanted I used the `schemeType` `linear` then I created a custom legend using `ngx-charts-legend`.

This is not a perfect solution since we cannot set 2 differents gradients.

```
  <div #containerRef class="d-flex" *ngIf="data.length && !loading">
    <ngx-charts-line-chart [view]="[containerRef.offsetWidth, 400]" [curve]="curve" [schemeType]="'linear'"
      [scheme]="colorScheme" [legend]="legend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxis]="xAxis" [yAxis]="yAxis" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [timeline]="timeline"
      [results]="data" [activeEntries]="activeEntries" [roundDomains]="true" [yScaleMin]="0" [yScaleMax]="100">
    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
    <div *ngIf="legend" class="chart-legend custom p-1">
      <ngx-charts-legend [data]="chartNames" [title]="'Legend'" [colors]="colors"
        (labelActivate)="legendLabelActivate($event)" (labelDeactivate)="legendLabelDeactivate($event)">
      </ngx-charts-legend>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
  public data: any[] = [];
  public view: any[];
  // options
  public legend: boolean = true;
  public chartNames: string[] = [];
  public showLabels: boolean = true;
  public animations: boolean = true;
  public xAxis: boolean = false;
  public yAxis: boolean = true;
  public yAxisTicks: number[] = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
  public showYAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  public showXAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  // xAxisLabel: string = 'Year';
  public activeEntries: any[];
  public yAxisLabel: string = 'Batt %';
  public timeline: boolean = true;
  public colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#a8385d', '#0000FF']
  };
  public colors: ColorHelper;
```